# Programmatically change the dropdown option using MUI TextField select

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to change the dropdown option programmatically, but it seems not working fine.

After setting the radius value, option label still remains unchanged. Anyone faced similar and solved this before?

```
const radiusVal = [
    {
        value: '25',
        label: '25 Miles',
    },
    {
        value: '50',
        label: '50 Miles',
    },
    {
        value: '100',
        label: '100 Miles',
    },
    {
        value: '200',
        label: '200 Miles',
    }
];

const [radius, setRadius] = useState();

const updateOption = () => {
  setRadius('200')
};

<TextField
   id="radius"
   select
   defaultValue='25'
   value={radius}
   className='bg-white'
   onChange={(e) => setRadius(e.target.value)}
   size='small'
>
    {radiusVal.map((option) => (
      <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
         {option.label}
      </MenuItem>
     ))}
</TextField>
```

In the above, radius is state value, and I tried to set the value as 200, but the option still remains 25.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3nrF.png)

Comment: can you show your full code plase ?

Comment: You never use the `radius` value except in the TextField, what do you try to achieve with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `updateOption` is never run cause it's not bounded to a lifecycle of your component. It exists but never going to be run.

What you should do if you want to set the value at the first render is to set the option in a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with an empty array of dependencies to make sure it's run only once:

```
export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [radius, setRadius] = React.useState("25");

   React.useEffect(() => {
    // here the value "200" is going to be set on
    // the first render of the component
    setRadius("200");
  }, []);

  return (
    <TextField
      id="radius"
      select
      value={radius}
      className="bg-white"
      onChange={(e) => setRadius(e.target.value)}
      size="small"
    >
      {radiusVal.map((option) => (
        <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

However, in the present usecase, it is more of an initial value hence you could save you a `useEffect` and provide it directly in the `useState`:  `React.useState("200")`

Comment: updateOption was supposed to be called in other events actually. :)
Anyway, I removed the defaultValue setting in TextField and provided the radius state with the default value as you did.
Magically, everything works fine now. Not sure why providing defaultValue not working.
Thank you, Gaël S

Comment: it's the difference between controlled or uncontrolled component.
Either you provide a `defaultValue` but no `value` and let the component handles its state internally or you provide a `value` and an `onChange` event and in that case, the textfield will let you manage everything (ignoring the defaultValue): https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled